# Passing data between two different storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, segue

I have two questions.

**1. First question**:

In my project, I have two different storyboard files: `A storyboard` and `B storyboard`.

I want to pass data (`nsstring`) from  `(A) controller of (A) storyboard` to  `(B) controller of  (B) storyboard`

how I make it?

**2. Second question**:

In the second storyboard, I have two controllers chained with a segue.

When I call segue in the code with this instruction:

```
[self.navigation controller performSegueWithIdentifier: @"secondViewSegue" sender:self];
```

I have a message: `"has no segue with identifier 'secondViewSegue' "`

Why?

Comment: Two storyboards? Aside from having separate storyboards for the different screen sizes of iPad vs iPhone, what practical use would there be for having separate storyboards on a single architecture? Is that even possible? If you want flexibility in the UI, why not use XIB's instead?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann multiple storyboards are fully supported.  Although the initial storyboard is loaded by default, any other can be loaded as needed.  There are viable use cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1/ A good way to do this is to make a separate model object that can be equally addressed from both locations. And the simplest way to do *that* is to add a property to the `@interface` section of your `AppDelegate.h` file, eg

```
  @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* sharedString;
```

To set and get it, you need to add typed access to the AppDelegate in any file that needs it:

```
  #include AppDelegate.h
```

Then you can use...

```
  AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  //to set (eg in A controller)
  appDelegate.sharedString = string;

  //to get (eg in B controller)
  NSString* string = appDelegate.sharedString;
```

As an alternative to a property, you could use a static variable in a header file:

```
 static NSString* staticString;
```

Which would be accessible to any object that `#imports` the header file. Not really the Objective-C way though.

For more elaborate cases, you may want to create a singleton object to access your model data.

2/ Try:

```
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"secondViewSegue" sender:self];
```

Ensure that the Segue is wired from your viewController, not it's Navigation Controller.

Comment: for the first question you're probably right, the only solution is to share the variable in AppDelegate ..

for the second question ok, I solved

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways to pass data between two different view controller in different storyboard. What I am using, I would like to share

**Swift 3**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName2", bundle: nil)
    let controller :NextViewController  = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NextVCIdentifier") as! NextViewController
    controller.NameofUser = Self.SelectedUser
```

Declare variable in next viewcontroller as

```
public var NameofUser:String = ""
```